# Restful file upload with laravel 4.2, not working when file is too big

Tags: php, rest, laravel

So I've been stuck on this for a while, thought it might help others who get this kind of error and maybe you genius guys could help me understand this better.

I've been trying to upload a file through user resource update (PUT method)
when the file was too big I would always get "405 Method not Allowed" error, if file was in the correct size I wouldn't get this kind of error.
php artisan routes (the problematic line):

`PUT user/{user} | user.update | UserController@update`

Even when trying to dd($_POST) or using try and catch, I was getting the same error.

`'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in C:\wamp\www\dsada\bootstrap\compiled.php:5693`

once moving to simple post, everything works perfectly.

my function code:

```
  if($_POST==null)
        return Redirect::back()->with(['user' => $this->user, 'flash_bad' => 'too BIG']);
    try{
        if(Input::file('picture')==null)
            return Redirect::back()->with(['user' => $this->user, 'flash_bad' => 'must pick a picture']);
        $picture = Image::make(Input::file('picture'));
        $picture_size = $picture->filesize();
        $max_size_megabytes = 1;
        if($picture_size > $max_size_megabytes*1024*1024)
            return Redirect::back()->with(['user' => $this->user, 'flash_bad' => 'too big 2']);

    }catch (Exception $e){
        return Redirect::back()->with(['user' => $this->user, 'flash_bad' => 'wrong file type']);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your view in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini. Change it like this, but using the sizes you think will solve your problem:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

You will need restart your services after updates.